# How to include one struts jsp in another when both jsps have <html:form>?

Tags: jsp, struts, action, struts-config, actionform

I have 2 jsps - jsp1 and jsp2.
Each jsp has a  defined.

**jsp1**

```
<html:form action="/action1" >
<html:hidden property="prop1" name="form1"/>
......
</html:form>
```

**jsp2**

```
<html:form action="/action2" >
<html:hidden property="prop1" name="form1"/>
......
</html:form>
```

This is the flow of data

```
tab1 - jsp1 - form1 - action1
tab2 - jsp2 - form2 - action2
```

Is there any way in which I can include jsp2 in tab1? It should look like this:

```
tab1 - jsp1+jsp2 
tab2 - jsp2
```

**I am looking for a way in which I can reuse the jsps, forms and actions because jsp2 is needed in both the tabs now.**
Tried several methods like `<html:include>, <tiles:insert>, changes to struts-config.xml, tiles-def.xml etc.` Nothing seems to work. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: try this <jsp:include page="/pages/jsp2.jsp" flush="true" />
or
<%@ include file="/pages/jsp2.jsp"%>

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
<%@ include file="jsp2.jsp"%>
```

in jsp1.jsp page, its working what you want. Here jsp2.jsp is reusable

Comment: @user811433, did you check ?